# How to authenticate in order to access Kibana 2.0?

Tags: kibana

Q: Kibana is great, but I want to make it so users have to authenticate in order to access it. How do I do that? A: This can be handled a number of ways. The best way is to run Kibana with Passenger and Apache or Nginx. There's sample configurations in the sample directory. You can then handle your preferred authentication mechanism with Apache or Nginx.

How do I do this? I do not use any of these programs. Could someone give me a basic overview of what I have to do? Any help would be nice I am a Student and learning but I need help to stay going, I don't know everything.

I am running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually even if you make a kind of authentication against Kibana it won't be enough. As you probably know Kibana runs over Elasticsearch, so even if you "limit" permissions to Kibana , everyone can still have access to elastic search and see existed indeces or even create new ones. So, the main question is whether you can manage AuthN && AuthZ against ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

For authentication you can integrate Kibana/ElasticSearch with any framework (example Play,Spring MVC etc) which ever your are using.Create a login page (authentication) using the framework,point the Kibana to web server/app server embedded in the framework and pass the kibana request to Elastic Search and response from Elastic Search to Kibana through this framework.Basically this framework will be a mediator between kibana and ElasticSearch.Also need to block the Elastic Search server port,so that no body could directly access the ES.

Kibana<-->Intermediate Framework<-->Elastic Search

Hope this helps!